# How do I 2D-plot my own function with two arguments?

Tags: matlab

I've started out with MATLAB a few hours ago and began with plotting some simple functions, e.g.:

```
k = -20:20;
a = 0.01;

x_k = exp(-a * k.^2)

f_1 = figure(1);
plot(k, x_k)
```

This works fine and plots each value of `k` on the x-axis, with its corresponding function response at the y-axis. Now I've defined my own function:

```
function [y] = triangle(t, a)
    if (a <= t) & (t <= 0)
        y = (1/a * t + 1) * a
    elseif (0 <= t) & (t <= a)
        y = (-1/a * t + 1) * a
    else
        error('Function not defined for these values')
    end
end
```

I now want to plot `triangle` for a range of `t` with a specific parameter `a`. So I call:

```
a = 1;
int = (2 * a) / 20;
t = -a:int:a;

f_1 = figure(1);
plot(t, triangle(t, a))
```

… but my function errors out because the entire `t` array (vector, I suppose?) is passed to it instead of each element of `t`.

**How do I plot my `triangle` function for a specific `a`, over a defined range?**

I've also tried `fplot(triangle(a), t)` (since [`fplot`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html) accepts a function as an argument)  but that again complains about `triangle` not receiving enough input arguments—rightly so, but I need to pass `a` to it as well.

Comment: Two minor comments on your code: use short-circuit ``&&`` instead of ``&`` in the if statements. This can be faster as if the lhs is false, the rhs is never evaluated. More importantly, it ensures that the if expression evaluates to a logical scalar (if it does not, you get an error).
Second, you don't need the end to close your function. That is normally used only for nested function or subfunctions. It doesn't hurt though, except for the extra level of indentation it introduces for the whole function body.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Diederick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of this is the that you pass a vector to your function `triangle` but you want to check every single if-statement for each single value of the vetor `t`. So either you use a `for`-loop within the function triangle or you could also do it by using this:

```
function [y] = triangle(t, a)
    y = ((a <= t) & (t <= 0)) .* ((1/a * t + 1) * a) + ((0 <= t) & (t <= a)) .* ((-1/a * t + 1) * a);
end
```

I know it looks somehow weird, but if you need me to explain it a bif more in detail, I can do this for you ;-)

**EDIT**: Let's shortly examine the problem: You pass a vector `t` to the function, which means that the first if statement `if (a <= t) & (t <= 0)` splitted looks like this:

```
(a <= t) % resulting in:
   ans =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1

(t <= 0) % resulting in:
ans =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

so combining them via the `AND` operator (`&` for vectors), this obviously gives you

```
ans =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

So this branch wont be executed. The elseif gives you:

```
(0 <= t)
ans =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1

(t <= a)
ans =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1

((0 <= t) & (t <= a))
ans =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

so this won't be executed either even though you'd want it to be executed for the second half of your values because you'd like to check the two statements for each value-pair on it's own.

So by leaving away the statements completely you could do it like I posted above: simply multiply the result of the logical statements elementwise with the piecewise function which will yield the result you want to calculate :-)

Comment: That's very interesting, thank you. Coming from a different background in programming, I would have never thought of that. The way you explained it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Thank you, glad it helped you. Yeah multiplying the logical results will automatically type casted into 0 and 1 (which will then decide wether the piecewise-function will provide any benefit to the result in that row :-)

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to define the `triangle` function so that it admits vector inputs. You and do it with [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.es/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html), which selects a range of values of `t` depending on a logical condition:

```
function [y] = triangle(t, a)
    y = NaN(size(t)); %// pre-allocate and define NaN as default return value
    ind = (a <= t) & (t <= 0); %// select first range 
    y(ind) = (1/a * t(ind) + 1) * a; %//compute output for first range 
    ind = (0 <= t) & (t <= a); %// select second range 
    y(ind) = (-1/a * t(ind) + 1) * a; %//compute output for second range 
end
```

This returns [`NaN`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/nan.html) for out-of-range values. As an example, for your `t`,

```
>> triangle(t, a)
ans =
  Columns 1 through 13
       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    1.0000    0.9000    0.8000
  Columns 14 through 21
    0.7000    0.6000    0.5000    0.4000    0.3000    0.2000    0.1000         0
```

Once you define the function like this, you can do `plot(t, triangle(t, a))`.

Answer (score 1):

To pass your function to `fplot`, you need to use an anonymous function (like what is called a lambda in many other programming languages).

This is done with the `@` syntax in matlab (see `help function_handle` for how to use this).

So your `fplot` try should be:

```
fplot(@(x) triangle(x,a), t([1 end]))
```

Note that the `t` input for `fplot` is the bounds in which you want to evaluate your function, not the values to evaluate itself (you can use bounds in combination with `fplot`'s third input argument for some control over that).

That said, as other posters also noted, the part of your example input where `t<0` end up right in your `else` branch and yields an error.